# Loading 1 API of another API's data

Tags: javascript, api, mapbox, p5.js

So I am trying to use the data (Specifically a country's iso3 code) from one API to load its LatLong from another API to then plot on a map.

The problem I am having is that I load the first API (Natural disaster locations) in preload() into an array, then I cannot access the information inside that array to get the iso3's of all the disasters listed unless I access it from draw().

The problem with that is when I then load the latlong data into the map it comes up as undefined, but when I load the latlong from preload() the disaster data is undefined.

Here is the code:[image]

This code works until mapM() is called and tries to load the latlong values from the temp array as they come back undefined, no matter where I these GET queries one is always undefined.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm pretty new to JS so go easy!

Comment: You are very likely trying to access asynchronous data in a synchronous code. It can be handled by using callbacks, promises, or async await. BTW why did you post a screenshot of your code instead of an actual code?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used this site in a while but I can see it makes things harder to answer haha, also all of that meant almost nothing to me, will this be a hard issue to fix?

Comment: In the future please post a [mcve] instead of a screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these are often best answered by reading through [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON):

> This method is asynchronous, meaning it may not finish before the next line in your sketch is executed.

This means that your `temp[i] = loadJSON(urlC);` line fires **but does not finish** before your `console.log(temp);` line executes.

This is because the `loadJSON()` function is **asynchronous** which means it runs in the background, not on the main thread. This is generally useful because you don't want your code to freeze every time you make a new request, but it also leads to bugs like yours.

To get around this, you can add a **callback function** to your `loadJSON()` lines. Again, from the reference:

```
function setup() {
  noLoop();
  var url =
   'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/' +
    'summary/all_day.geojson';
  loadJSON(url, drawEarthquake);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
}

function drawEarthquake(earthquakes) {
  // Get the magnitude and name of the earthquake out of the loaded JSON
  var earthquakeMag = earthquakes.features[0].properties.mag;
  var earthquakeName = earthquakes.features[0].properties.place;
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, earthquakeMag * 10, earthquakeMag * 10);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text(earthquakeName, 0, height - 30, width, 30);
}
```

Notice that the `drawEarthquake()` function is passed into the `loadJSON()` function. When the `loadJSON()` function completes, it will call the `drawEarthequake()` function automatically.

You probably want to do something similar.